# Is singleton object creates per session or per server startup in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I didnt get any answer for this in the internet, please send answers.

Is singleton object creates per session or per server startup in java.

Lets assume db connection object is singleton in my application, i deployed my application in the sever.

Questions

1. Is connection(singleton) exists in the server now. Since all .class files existed in the release.
2. User typed the home page url(home page doesnt need connection object, just has content in the html page), page was loaded. Is connection(singleton) exists in the server now.
3. User tried to login now, which needs connection objection. Will this first request creates singleton object.
4. Lets say connection object created, is this object uses for all the users around the world
5. How long this connection objects
6. Will next version deployment clears the singleton object.

please answer.

Comment: please send questions.

Comment: Surely, only one question instance is permitted?

Comment: show me your code, please tell us what is the server, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton instance gets created per ClassLoader. If your application uses a single ClassLoader, then your singleton(s) is(are) available through all the live of the JVM.

---

Your question is very broad (6 questions in one) and it's already covered in several posts through this site and blog entries. Still, here's a brief explanation on the subject:

> Lets assume db connection object is singleton in my application

This is a **must not**. Your database connection **MUST NEVER BE** (yes, bolded and with capitals to make sure you and every reader never make this mistake) a singleton object. Your `Connection con` **MUST NOT** be part of a singleton to keep it open all the time. Instead, use a proper database connection pool that will take care of opening the necessary physical database connections and keep them alive through the live of your application.

Now, to your specific questions:

> 1. Is connection(singleton) exists in the server now. Since all .class files existed in the release.

It will exists when the ClassLoader initializes it. This means, the object will be initialized the first time any piece of code has to call to your singleton reference. If no line of code executed during the deployment of your application has made a call to your singleton reference, then it's not created (yet).

> 2. User typed the home page url(home page doesnt need connection object, just has content in the html page), page was loaded. Is connection(singleton) exists in the server now.

This was explained in 1.

> 3. User tried to login now, which needs connection objection. Will this first request creates singleton object.

The answer can be inferred from 1.

> 4. Lets say connection object created, is this object uses for all the users around the world

Yes.

> 5. How long this connection objects

It will live until the class is unloaded from the ClassLoader. Depending on the execution parameters sent to the JVM, this could mean that the class will never be unloaded, which mean you have generated a memory leak and probably a connection that will be always opened (if you have made sure that this physical database connection must not die in order to reinvent the wheel rather than using a database connection pool). If the ClassLoader will never unload the classes, then this singleton object will *die* when the JVM stops.

> 6. Will next version deployment clears the singleton object

From 5: **NO**.

As you can see, it is a **VERY BAD IDEA** the solely idea of creating a singleton in your application (despite the fact if it's for database connection or whatever you want/need) unless you specifically know what you're doing and you know what parameters to send to the JVM. Otherwise, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, Luiggi Mendoza